# Form does not post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

i have the following html code:

```
<form class="dropzone" id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                   <!-- multistep form -->


    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Post an Image</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Fill in Some General Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">As Simple As This</h3>
        <input type="text" name="update" id="title" placeholder="Update Title" />
        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Short Description/Add On"></textarea>    
         <input type="date" name="expire" id="expire" placeholder="Expire By" value="Expire By" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Upload Image</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We currently only support images.</h3>
        <div class="dropzone-previews dz-message" id="dropzonePreview">

        </div>

        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>

</form>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    Dropzone.options.msform = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  url: "filepostupload.php",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  autoDiscover: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  maxFiles: 5,
  paramName: "file",
   previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
   clickable:'#dropzonePreview', //used for specifying the previews div
   //used this but now i cannot click on previews div to showup the file select dialog box


  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
     this.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
       if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
           var update =  $('#title').val(); 
        var description =  $('#description').val(); 
        var expiry =  $('#expire').val();
        var groupid =  <?php echo $groupid ?>;
     var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "updatesnofile.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { update:update, description:description, expiry:expiry, groupid:groupid},
                        dataType:"text",

                   success: function(data) { 
                   if (data=="success") {
                    alert('success');


                   } else  {

                    alert(data);

                   }  
                   },
                   error: function(request, err){ 


                  alert(err);



                   }
                 });    
       }else {
      myDropzone.processQueue();

       }
    });



    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sending", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.
    });
    this.on("success", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.
      alert(response);
    });
    this.on("error", function(files, response) {
     alert("error");
    });
  }

}
    </script>
```

And my php script that does the file upload is :

```
<?php  
session_start();
 require 'config.php';
 //I'm using mysql_ as an example, it should be PDO

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$foldername = "updatefiles/";
if (isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['expiry']) && isset($_POST['groupid'])){
    $title= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST['update']));
    $description= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST['description']));
    $expire= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST['expiry']));
    $groupid= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST['groupid']));

    $fileupload = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $foldername . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    $fileupload = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
    $fileType = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_FILES['file']['type']);
    $fileSize = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_FILES['file']['size']);
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"START TRANSACTION;");
  $ins = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO posts (category, description, posttitle, userid, expire, group_id) VALUES ('updates','".$description."', '".$title."','{$_SESSION['userid']}', '".$expire."','".$groupid."' )");
  if (!$ins) {
    // fail
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"ROLLBACK");
    echo"error with first insert";
    return FALSE;

  }

  $upd = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET @post_id_in_posts = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
  if (!$upd) {
    // fail
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"ROLLBACK");
    echo"error with setting postid";
    return FALSE;
  }

  $del = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO files (post_id,f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES (@post_id_in_posts,'".$fileupload."', '".$fileType."', '".$fileSize."')");
  if (!$del) {
    // fail
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"ROLLBACK"); 
    echo "Error with Second Insert!";
    return FALSE;
  }

  // All succeeded
  mysqli_query($mysqli,"COMMIT"); 
  echo"success";
    return TRUE;

}else {
echo"formwasnotsubmitted";  


}

?>
```

However, it keeps telling me that the form was not submitted (which means the posting of the form by drop zone fails, and therefore the data isn't posted over when there are files, the ajax works though when there are NO files), can anyone find out why? thanks!

I have managed to find the mistake, it is something to do with the way Dropzone sends the form data!

Comment: Check the HTTP POST data using something like Firebug or built-in tools.also check the `var_dump($_POST);` output.

Comment: vardump gives me the correct $_POST data but my own error checks say that isset is not getting the data..

Comment: Where Do you get this ->  isset is not getting the data. ????????

Comment: hi there, i actually added my own error catching system, and it tells me that the isset is the one failing to even get the POSTED data

Comment: First of, try to add an "action" atribute to your form. And as a second tought of mine: You can't use any mysql or mysqli function without initializing a connection first.

Comment: hi there I'm using drop zone, which acts as an automatic ajax submitter, with the url specified inside, I have rectified the issue, it is a really silly mistake. Thanks anyway!